# Can cache coherency protocols like snooping coherence be implemented in hardware(RTL)?

Tags: caching, architecture, verilog, processor

Can cache coherency protocols like snooping coherence protocol and MESI/MOESI be implemented in hardware(RTL)? I am designing an RTL for multicore cache environment, and need to implement the cache coherency protool in that to get coherent and consistent data for all the processors. This is just an academic exercise.

Any leads would indeed be helpful. I have the state diagram for MSI, should I try to implement a FSM from that first? I am developing the code for synthesizable verilog/systemverilog.

The FSM should be different for every cache block, so is there a mux connected to the FSM state machine controller like below?

[image]

Comment: Given that real CPUs have been using (variants of) MESI for years, it's obvious that it is implementable in hardware!  How is this a real question?

Comment: I was not aware that it is implementable in hardware. Does each cache line have its own FSM?

Comment: IDK exactly *how* Intel/AMD/ARM/everyone else design their caches, but real caches in real hardware use MESI / MOESI / MESIF / whatever other variant, heavily optimized for pipelined operation with multiple outstanding misses, multiple read and write ports, and all the usual things that modern high performance caches need.  (And that a learning exercise like yours probably won't.)  I'm not a hardware guy, so I can't tell you anything more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can cache coherency protocols like snooping coherence protocol and MESI/MOESI be implemented in hardware(RTL)?

Yes. They have been implemented in VLSI for years, as the people who have commented already stated.

> should I try to implement a FSM [for [Modified/Shared/Invalid (MSI) cache-coherence protocol]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSI_protocol) first?

I suppose so. It is certainly one of the easier ones. You didn't mention whether or not you've already implemented a basic cache controller or not. I feel like you should start with a single-processor cache controller first and then expand it to peek at other processor's caches from there.

Personally, I found *Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/Software Interface Fifth Edition* very helpful when getting into cache architectures. I attached a screen shot of a piece of the book which talks about building a cache controller.

[image: Using a finite state machine to control a simple cache]

---

From that point, you might look at resources like these, which dive into an architectural design of cache controllers with cache-coherency functionalities. I pulled these up with basic Google searches.

- ["Implementing Cache Controllers"](http://www.engr.colostate.edu/~sudeep/teaching/reading_452/CD5.9-P374493.pdf)
- ["Designing a Snoopy Cache"](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~airturk/others/2.pdf)

> is there a mux connected to the FSM state machine controller like below?

To access a block/line in the cache, yes. However, remember that your coherency controller may not need to have access to the data in the cache. Your coherency logic most likely only needs to read and/or modify the state bits of the block. This could save you some bit width. So I might draw my diagram like this:

[image]

This is just an idea, not a concrete "this is how you *should* do it" answer.

Since you're using MSI, you really only need 2 bits to represent those three states. Getting and outputting only 2 bits should be more efficient than getting the whole entire block with its data for the coherency controller.

```
// Note this code has not been tested. It is simply for illustrative purposes only.
module <cache name> (

input [X:0] address,
output logic [1:0] block_state

);

    // Cache memory blocks (32-bits of data. 2 bits of "state" info)
    logic [33:0] cache_mem [0:N];

    // Give index bits of address a name
    wire [Y:0] address_index;
    assign address_index[Y:0] = address[A:B];

    // Output the state bits of the selected cache block.
    assign block_state[1:0] = cache_mem[33:32][address_index];

endmodule
```

Hopefully some of that is helpful for you! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the links. Sorry to not mention, but I have already implemented the cache controller, following the exact same links you shared. So now, I have my multiple processors(simple MIPS), each having its own cache(designed cache memory and controller) and I have a shared RAM and shared memory controller. Till this point, I am fine. I have also read those links now. The only point of confusion remians as to the mux diagram. If you can also answer how the connection is, it would be helpful.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji I assume that MUX is supposed to be your access to your cache line(s). The way you access your cache would really depend on if you have a direct mapped, x-way set associative, or fully associative cache. It looked kind of like you were doing direct mapped, with the way your diagram is drawn. I can't say for sure though. How did you intend to map your cache?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is direct mapped. I hope my diagram is correct for direct mapped? How would it be for say fully associative or 2-way associative?

Comment: I am just going to assume that you have a 4-word block and that your cache is byte-addressable. You can choose to modify this however you feel like. But you **must** determine how you're going to access your cache before you start building it. One example of a modification would be to remove the byte-addressing functionality and only output full 32-bit words. However you decide, it greatly affects how you are going to access your cache.

Comment: With my above example if a direct mapped, 4-word block, byte-addressable cache, you would have an address with fields like this: `msb [tag][index][WiB][biW] lsb` where "WiB" = Word in Block and "biW" = byte in Word.

Comment: I apologize. I was typing to work out your problem in my head. Should have been typing into Notepad or something and not this comment section. Anyway, what I was intending to say is that your MUX you drew could be in one of three places, I think. 1) is selecting the line (block) in the cache which "hit" 2) is selecting the word in the block (WiB) 3) is selecting the byte in the word. I think what you were probably trying to indicate is the MUX to select the line (block) in the cache. [This is a good diagram](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/00au/CSE378-00.Lec26/img003.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at the openPiton project at Princeton ([openPiton](http://parallel.princeton.edu/openpiton/)). It is a research framework that allows you to synthesize and tape out multi-core designs.